# How to access background while modal active in react-native-modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-navigation, react-native-modal

I am trying to implement a page where top part of page is static and bottom part keeps on changing. I was able to achieve this using react-native-modal. But the problem is the back arrow button which is always supposed to be on the top of page becomes inaccessible entire time. I want to access the button even when modal is active.
Any help will be really appreciated cause **it's not available anywhere**, I went through the entire react native and react-native-modal docs related to this